# Is there any convex tight upper bound (major) for $f(\mathbf{x},Y) = \mathbf x^T Y \mathbf x$?

Tags: optimization

In a minimization problem, I have this expression in my objective function

$$f(\mathbf{x},Y) = \mathbf x^T Y \mathbf x,$$
for $(\mathbf x,Y)\in \Omega = \{Y\succ 0,x\neq0\}$.

So the function is biconvex, but not convex as a whole, (one eigenvalue is always negative in the Hessian).
I was trying to majorize it. i.e. to find a function $F$ tight around a point $(\mathbf x_0,Y_0)$ such that:
$$F(\mathbf x_0,Y_0,\mathbf x,Y) = f(\mathbf x_0,Y_0),$$
$$F(\mathbf x_0,Y_0,\mathbf x,Y) \geq f(\mathbf x,Y),$$
$$\forall\; (\mathbf x_0,Y_0),(\mathbf x,Y)\in \Omega.$$
I know I can use a biconvex alternating procedure but, I think, if I could making it by majorization-minimization I could prove convergence.

Comment: Do you want convexity of $F$ w.r.t. $(x,Y)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't explain it in the body, $F$ must be convex w.r.t. $(x,Y), \forall (x_0,Y_0) \in \Omega$

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you find anything useful about this?